# Latex/MathJax question: How to number equations?

Tags: support, mathjax

Is it possible to number equations when posting questions at physics stack exchange, or any other stack exchange site enabled with MathJax?

I have tried `\begin{equation} \end{equation}`.

Comment: And on this topic, for those familiar with Tex but new to MathJax: both starred and unstarred versions of equation, align, and gather can be used, but they are identical and function as the starred variants (no numbers) unless `\tag` is used.

Answer (score 25):

Yes, there is a `\tag{}` command. E.g.

`$$ 1+1=2 \tag{1} $$`

produces

$$  1+1=2 \tag{1} $$

Comment: Perfect. Thanks. It provides right margin numbering.

Comment: How do you align a non-numbered equation with that?  For example, if I had several intermediate steps that led up to $1+1=2$, but didn't want them numbered, how would I format those steps?

Comment: If you mean outside MathJax, it is probably best to ask on [tex.se], but it sounds partly like a job for the [align](https://www.google.com/search?as_q=latex+align) command.