# How to write equations with automatic equation numbering like \label{ref} in latex?

Tags: support, feature-request, mathjax

$$

\begin{align}

a = b

\label{my equation}

\end{align}

$$

Equation \ref{my equation} is my equation.

I plan on editing my question [Alternative representation of the covariant derivative?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/101464/alternative-representation-of-the-covariant-derivative) to make it more compact and concise, but it would be nice to save time and not have to renumber all of the equations [manually](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2887/2451) a third time.

Comment: As linked, there isn't the ability to do it automatically, you have to use `\tag{}` (MathJax doesn't process it). Curiously, however, using `$\ref{ref1}$` in the body does produce a (dead) hyperlink.

Comment: It's worth noting that you don't need to tag *every* equation in your posts - just the ones that you refer to later on. If you have a quick browse you'll see that very few posts use them at all. You certainly don't need to tag substages of a calculation. Tagging is also a form of emphasis, *but emphasis is lost if you use it on a lot of text, so it should be used only on the bits that* really *matter*. See?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\tag{something to refer back to}`

$$ C^2 = A^2 + B^2 \,. \tag{PT} $$

And then later you write

Referring back to (PT) we see that side the length of the hypotenuse is clearly 13.

---

You have to type the refernces yourself. I tend to use `*`, `**`, `$\dag$` and `$\ddag$`, or (as above) mnemonics for Physics SE posts.